# calculus, slope of a tangent line with given point

Tags: calculus

What is the slope of the tangent line $f(x) = x^3 -(1/3)x^2$ at $(1, 2/3$)

I already did the first derivative, which gave me, $3x^2-2/3x$

so am i right for just doing
 3(1)^2-(2/3)(1) = 7/3 = 2 (1/3) is this my answer?

Comment: $f'(x)=3x^2-\frac{2}{3}x$

Comment: 3x^2-2/3? or $3x^2-2/3x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative is
$$
f'(x) = 3x^2 - (2/3)x.
$$

You want to find the slope at the point $(1, 2/3)$. At this point $x = 1$, so the slope is the derivative at $1$:
$$
f'(x) = 3 - 2/3 = \dots
$$

Comment: okay perfect, so the 2/3 in (1,2/3) the nothing, right? i just plug in one, f(1)=3(1)^2-(2/3)(1)=7/3 which comes out to 2 1/3

Comment: @Tochoa2015: Yes, you get the $2/3$ from $f(1)$.